# How to create angular schematic for repeating files?

Tags: angular, angular-schematics

There is one large project in which small applications are created.
In each such application there are many identical index.html / tslint.json / app files
I understand that through angular schematics this can be automated.

I figured out how to create files using angular schematics. And how to make files repeat?

I want when I called the command schematics .:myapp --name=test
I created an application with filled files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People will tell you to be more specific.

[here a good example- begginer/intermedite](https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/total-guide-to-custom-angular-schematics-5c50cf90cdb4)

[begginer tutorial](https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/%EF%B8%8F-how-to-create-your-first-custom-angular-schematics-with-ease-%EF%B8%8F-bca859f3055d)

Comment: I read these articles, but did not find an answer for myself.
In fact, I just need to copy files